# 404 and HTTPHandler Errors when deploying service stack

Tags: asp.net, web-services, servicestack

I am currently having difficulty deploying a Service Stack service to our UAT production server. In our development and testing environments the service functions correctly and can be accessed as expected.

When the website is deployed to the UAT server however, the service is unavailable and returns a 404 error.

When the application was first deployed, an exception was raised due to missing MVC dlls. These dlls were all placed into the bin folder and the application returned a 404 error.

In the UAT environment the service is added, as an application to an IIS website.

It maybe that the application error page is returning the wrong error message, as if the service is deployed as a standalone site the application runs and returns an HTTPHandler issue for a GET request exactly like this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577159/service-stack-handler-for-request-not-found). However, the config file is already setup as the answer suggests.

Please can anyone help as this is causing a real problem for me at the moment?

Comment: Environment issues like these are really hard for others to troubleshoot. We would need more information about the IIS settings and your imporatant web.config settings to even get started.

Comment: The configuration of the config files was causing a problem, however there was also another issue regarding the app pool in which the application was running. This issue is now closed and I will mark it as such shortly. Thankyou for looking at this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by a number of factors.

1:) The parent site web config had not been setup correctly with  tags around the appropriat setions ( and  )

```
<location path="xxxxxxx">
    <system.web>
  <customErrors mode="Off"/>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpHandlers>
          <add path="*" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.EndPoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*" />
        </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
          <add path="*" name="ServiceStack.Factory" type="ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.ServiceStackHttpHandlerFactory, ServiceStack" verb="*"     preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="Unspecified" allowPathInfo="true" />
        </handlers>
   </system.webServer>
</loaction>
```

2:) One of the dlls had been built to the wrong architecture for the app pool. Enabling 32 bit applications for the app pool solved this.

In short there were a number of configuration issues that had not been setup before deployment to the testing environment.